# How to take more than 1000 records in array using rails 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-2, ruby-1.8.7

How to take more than 1000 records from oracle database using rails 2

```
 @business_users_loc = User.find(:all,:conditions=>"(users.role_id NOT IN ('#{Role[:submember].id}') AND locations.mac_id IS NOT NULL and users.mac_id IS NOT NULL and locations.location_type='Business')",:order => 'users.created_at DESC',:joins=>:locations,:include=>[{:locations=>[:social_network_mac_id,{:pronto_gateway=>[:heartbeat]},:fb_sponsors_fanpage]}],:select=>"distinct(users.login_slug), users.created_at, users.email, users.login, users.id")
```

when i tried above query i got this error

```
 ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: OCIError: ORA-01795: maximum number of expressions in a list is 1000: SELECT * FROM "LOCATIONS" WHERE ("LOCATIONS"."ID" IN (19228,18667,14642,15727,13541,14700,....
```

Can you help me please....

Answer (score 0):

You may have a look at [`find_in_batches`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Batches/ClassMethods/find_in_batches)  method.

```
options = {
 :conditions=>"users.role_id NOT IN ('#{Role[:submember].id}')",
 :batch_size => 1010
}
User.find_in_batches(options) do |group|
  # YOUR CODE
end
```

Change the value of `:batch_size` as per the need ; the default is 1000.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
User.find_in_batches(:all,:conditions=>"users.role_id NOT IN ('#{Role[:submember].id}')") do |users|
 users.each do |user|
  #do somthing
 end
end
```